# Hazeltask: MojoExecutionException while signing artifact with maven-gpg-plugin

Tags: java, maven, gnupg

I'm trying to build [Hazeltask](https://github.com/jclawson/hazeltask) on my local with `mvn clean install`. How to fix the next error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Hazeltask Parent POM .............................. FAILURE [0.385s]
[INFO] Hazeltask ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.490s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Mar 21 12:25:19 EET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-artifacts) on project hazeltask-parent: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-artifacts) on project hazeltask-parent: Exit code: 2
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exit code: 2
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSigner.generateSignatureForFile(GpgSigner.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.AbstractGpgSigner.generateSignatureForArtifact(AbstractGpgSigner.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.gpg.GpgSignAttachedMojo.execute(GpgSignAttachedMojo.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Do not post text as screen shots please, but copy-paste them into your question. Makes it easier to read and work with for people wanting to answer your question, and later on enables others searching for the error message to actually find the question (and hopefully solution).

Comment: Regarding your actual question, three guesses: you might be missing GnuPG at all, `gpg` is not in your path, or the build process wants to sign with some OpenPGP key you do not have available.

Comment: @JensErat `which gpg` says `/usr/local/bin/gpg`. That means I need to ask an author of Hazeltask to give me some open key? May I remove gpg from maven dependencies?

Comment: I don't know what the exact problem is. Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`? Otherwise, asking the author might be a reasonable idea, at least answering this requires deeper insight in the build process.

Comment: @JensErat right, `usr/local/bin` is my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

If not already done run the gpg-agent daemon

```
gpg-agent --daemon
```

If you don't have one, generate a key pair:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

Then clone the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/jclawson/hazeltask.git
```

and run the build (your passphrase will be asked)

```
mvn clean install
```